# ActiveQt example - COM App - Class naming

Tags: visual-studio, qt, activeqt

I’m tring to add OLE support to my program. I started by compiling one of the Qt examples:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/activeqt-comapp.html

This example, export 1 class and 2 types:

```
QAXCLASS(Application)
QAXTYPE(Document)
QAXTYPE(DocumentList)
```

In order to test it, I import it in Microsft Visual C++ (add class, MFC class from Typelib)
The problem is that, after import, my classes are renamed:

```
CApplication
CDocument
CDocumentList
```

So when I call **CApplication::Getdocuments()** it returns a **DocumentList*** and this class is unknown!
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: tested in a VB project, and it works fine! So there must be something wrong when importing the tlb in VC++

Comment: The "MFC class from Typelib" option is rather awful.  It does generate class names that have a C prefix.  They are *wrappers*, using late binding to your COM classes.  What you get back from Getdocuments() should be an IDispatch*, not a DocumentList*.  This is all rather a bad idea, use the #import directive instead.

Comment: Could you please detail your answer, or point me on a webpage? The option "MFC class from Typelib" generate a class. In the header, the first line is a #import of my tlb. What should I do instead?

Comment: Just start at the MSDN page for #import and continue reading at the "Compiler COM support" link to understand how to use the smart pointers.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx